# White outdoor riding mower wont start

Tags: fuel-system, small-engine, cranks-wont-run, lawnmower

Mower was running let sit for 2 months so I drained the gas took bowls off carbs cleaned everything .still won't start unless I spray carbs acts like not getting gas

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it's acting like it's not getting gas, it probably isn't. More likely it's a fueling issue and the carbs aren't doing their thing.

Comment: If carbs are 'old school' and not getting gas, you may have to remove them for disassembly and cleaning. If regular unleaded is used, gasoline left in carbs may create clogs in fuel lines and carb passageways. The residue from moisture calcifying into a hard blockage restricting fuel flow. If you go this route and do find buildup of residue then consider using a fuel treatment to blend with fuel in the tank to reduce fuel blockage from water. Ethanol used in gasoline absorbs water but not forever if fuel is left in tanks and carbs.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of carburetor failure in my experience is the needles clogging. They can be cleaned with a very fine wire, however replacing them, especially if they are adjustable, can be tedious.

The main jet is likely clogged with dirt, gelled fuel, or something else. The one in the below photo does not appear to be adjustable, so it should be fully seated when replaced, however an adjustable one will have a process to get it placed in the right spot - this will be in an owners' manual for the carburetor or the engine.

[image]

An easy way to check if there is fuel is to pull the spark plug immediately after cranking a few times. If it appears wet, there is fuel, and fuel supply is not your problem (though bad gas might be).